# Creating a dynamic model / understanding PACF

Tags: r

I have to variables:

SKI = a price index who shows how my currency is compared to other currencies

VM = Value/quantity of exported fish from my country.

My goal for this is to see how changes in the index (SKI) affects the total value of the exported fish.
I did a ADF-test on both of the variables, but on one of them I got a p-value that forced med to change the variables:

```
data["SKI_ret"] = log(data$SKI) - lag(log(data$SKI))
data["VM_ret"] = log(data$VM) - lag(log(data$VM))
```

I then did PACF-tests:

```
pacf(data$SKI_ret)
pacf(data$VM_ret)
```

And got the following results:

[VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ZPa.jpg)
[SKI-index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Ky3.jpg)

My next step is to make a dynamic model by using "dynlm". The problem is that I don't know how many lags of each variable I can include. Can someone please help?

Thanks.